# Complex integral $\int_C{e^{z^3}z^2}dz$ over a parameterized curve $z(t)=t+t^{10}i$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Compute $\int_C{e^{z^3}z^2}dz$ where C is given by $z(t)=t+t^{10}i$, where  $t\in [0,1]$.

I think this is easier than I am making it, but can we just do u-substitution on this, and then integrate the $e^u \,du$, or is this more complicated than I am thinking? I have been overthinking these types of problems quite a lot and I'm unsure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inasmuch as the antiderivative of $z^2e^{z^3}$ is $\frac13 e^{z^3}$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_C z^2e^{z^3}\,dz&=\left.\left(\frac13e^{z^3}\right)\right|_{z=0}^{z=1+i}\\\\
&=\frac13 \left(e^{(1+i)^3}-1\right)
\end{align}$$

And you can simplify.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.